# Twinview: 2 monitors difference resolutions with NVIDIA

Tags: xorg, nvidia, monitors, resolution, twinview

I'm successfully using twinview to drive 2 monitors for my home theatre computer (one in the case, one projector).  I recently upgraded my projector and now the two screens have vastly different resolutions (1920x1200, 848x400).  As a result twinview is forcing me to use very little of my projector resolution (scaling up a fuzzy image), OR, overdrive the little screen until is shuts off with "OUT OF RANGE" message but have a great projector image.

I would like to drive the projector at full resolution, and have the (nvidia) driver/X scale this same image down to 848x400 for my small screen.

Is this possible?  I'm running Centos 6.3 x64 with X.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting two separate X screens up to replace TwinView will solve your problem?
Checkout your `xorg.conf` file for sections: `ServerLayout`, `Monitor`, `Device` and `Screen`, mine looks more or less like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 520"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then I can set two different screen resolutions for each screen. There are some disadventages of this, like impossibility to move windows from one screen to another, but to avoid them you could try to setup Xinerama.

Well, you gotta try to find out what's the best for you.

Comment: I know I can setup 2 different screens (with different resolutions), but how do I cause the content to be mirrored from one screen to the other then?

Comment: I haven't noticed that you want to mirror your screens and in this case I don't think you can do such thing...